# How and when to repair seals in concrete porch and steps?

Tags: concrete, stairs, sealing, porch

What product should I use to seal the gap between my sinking front step and the porch pad? How do I remove the old failing seal?

Should I seal the gap between the concrete porch in the house? What product should I use?

[image: the step]

[image: porch to house]

[image: seal closeup]

[image: another closeup of porch to house]

Comment: It does not look like the cracks caused by settlement, so clean out the loose grout and seal all gaps with a waterproof-flexible sealant that will stick for a long time.